# Same code run on SQL Server 2014 but it gives error while running on higher version like 2016,2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am migrating the data from Microsoft SQL Server to Postgres, so while migrating I got a code which will take bcp for all the table from selected database and throws the output in the form of CSV file in the directory defined in the code.

While running the dynamic SQL statement in Microsoft SQL Server 2014, it ran flawlessly, but the same code run on other versions like SQL Server 2012,2016,2017 causes an error.

I have checked all BCP version for all SQL Server versions, they are the same.

```
declare @databaseName varchar(100)
declare @folderPath varchar(100)='C:\Data\'
set @databaseName = DB_NAME()

--Export query preparation
select ROW_NUMBER() over (
        order by (
                select 1
                )
        ) rownum
    ,'select * FROM ' + @databaseName + '.' + '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '].[' + t.name + ']' as col1
    ,'select ' + STUFF((
            select ',' + case 
                    when DATA_TYPE = 'datetime'
                        or DATA_TYPE = 'datetime2'
                        then ' Isnull(nullif(convert(nvarchar(28),' + COLUMN_NAME + + ' ,121) ,' + char(39) + char(39) + '), ' + char(39) + 'null' + char(39) + ')'
                    when DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
                        or DATA_TYPE = 'nvarchar'
                        then @databaseName + '.dbo.GetString(' + COLUMN_NAME + ')'
                    when DATA_TYPE = 'binary'
                        or DATA_TYPE = 'varbinary'
                        or DATA_TYPE = 'image'
                        then 'substring(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(' + COLUMN_NAME + '), 3, len(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(' + COLUMN_NAME + ')))'
                    else ' Isnull(nullif(cast(' + COLUMN_NAME + + ' as nvarchar(max)) ,' + char(39) + char(39) + '), ' + char(39) + 'null' + char(39) + ')'
                    end
            from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            where TABLE_NAME = t.name
                and TABLE_SCHEMA = schema_name(schema_id)
            order by table_schema
                ,table_name
                ,ordinal_position
            for xml PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') + ' FROM ' + @databaseName + '.' + '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '].[' + t.name + ']' as col2
    ,SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '."' + t.name + '"' as col3
into tempQueries
from sys.tables t

select * into  tempQueriesCopy from tempQueries
--Export with bcp script
declare @query1 varchar(MAX)
declare @query2 varchar(MAX)
declare @table varchar(MAX)
declare @row int = 0

while exists (
        select top 1 rownum
        from tempQueries
        )
begin
    select top 1 @query1 = col2
        ,@query2 = col2
        ,@row = rownum
        ,@table = col3
    from tempQueries

    declare @sql varchar(8000) = ''

    select @sql = 'bcp "' + @query2 + '" queryout "' + @folderPath + replace( @table,'"','') + '.csv" -c -t~ -T -S' + @@servername

    print @sql

    exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql

    delete
    from tempQueries
    where rownum = @row
end


---- To allow advanced options to be changed.  
--EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
--GO  
---- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.  
--RECONFIGURE;  
--GO  
---- To enable the feature.  
--EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
--GO  
---- To update the currently configured value for this feature.  
--RECONFIGURE;  
--GO
```

**Error:-**

```
output  
Copy direction must be either 'in' or 'out'.    
Syntax Error in 'queryout'. 
usage: bcp [[db_name.]owner.]table_name[:slice_num] [partition pname] {in | out} [filename] 
    [-m maxerrors] [-f formatfile] [-e errfile] [-d discardfileprefix] 
    [-F firstrow] [-L lastrow] [-b batchsize]
    [-n] [-c] [-t field_terminator] [-r row_terminator]
    [-U username] [-P password] [-I interfaces_file] [-S server]
    [-a display_charset] [-z language] [-v]
    [-i input_file] [-o output_file] 
    [-A packet size] [-J client character set] 
    [-T text or image size] [-E] [-g id_start_value] [-N] [-W] [-X]
    [-M LabelName LabelValue] [-labeled]
    [-K keytab_file] [-R remote_server_principal] [-C]
    [-V [security_options]] [-Z security_mechanism] [-Q] [-Y]
    [-y sybase directory] [-x trusted.txt_file]
    [--clienterr errfile] [--maxconn maximum_connections]
    [--show-fi] [--hide-vcc]
    [--colpasswd [[[db_name.[owner].]table_name.]column_name [password]]]
    [--keypasswd [[db_name.[owner].]key_name [password]]]
    [--initstring ASE initialization string] [--quoted-fname]
    [--filemode file_permission]
NULL
```

Comment: And how can you - or anyone else - debug your dynamically generated code if you cannot **see** the statement you attempt to execute? Post the complete statement (which your code prints) that you pass to xp_cmdshell.

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve] for some additional guidance on how to post effective questions.